# Pass List to RESTful webservice

Tags: java, jersey

Is there a way to pass a list to RESTFul web service method in Jersey? Something like @PathParam("list") List list?

Answer (score 3):

Hope that this will help you

### Java code

```
import java.util.List;

@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getCustomers(
            @QueryParam("start") int start,
            @QueryParam("size") int size,
            @QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### Passing value from javascript using AJAX

Ajax call url : `/customers?orderBy=name&orderBy=address&orderBy=...`

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the best way to send a **list** via POST from the client to a REST service is by using the `@FormParam`.
**If you add a parameter twice or more times to the form, it will result into a list on the server's side.**

Using the `@FormParam`means on client side you generate a `com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form` and add some form parameters like shown below. Then you add the filled form to the post like that: `service.path(..) ... .post(X.class, form)` (see example code).

Example-code for the **client side**:

```
public String testMethodForList() {

    Form form = new Form();
    form.add("list", "first String");
    form.add("list", "second String");
    form.add("list", "third String");

    return service
            .path("bestellung")
            .path("add")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
            .post(String.class, form);
}
```

Example-Code for **server side**:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String testMethodForList(       
    @FormParam("list") List<String> list {

    return "The list has " + list.size() + " entries: " 
           + list.get(0) + ", " + list.get(1) + ", " + list.get(2) +".";
}
```

The **return String** will be:

> The list has 3 entries: first String, second String, third String.

**Note:**

- The MediaTypes of `@Consumes` on server side and `.type()` on client
  side have to be identical as well as `@Produces` and `.accept()`.
- You can NOT send objects other than String, Integer etc. via 
  `@FormParam`. In case of an object you'll have to convert it to XML
  or JSON String and re-convert it on the server side. For how to convert see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694297)**.
- You can also pass a List to the form like `form.add(someList)`, but this will result in a String containing the list's entries on server side. It will look like: `[first String, second String, third String]`. You'd have to split the String on server side at "," and cut off the square brackets for extracting the single entiries from it.

Comment: list can also be passed as query params or some standard data format like json, xml, yaml or plain text.

Comment: Yes it can. But because you would openly pass all the XML/JSON String in a `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` **via the URL** (which could be VERY long then, maybe it even get's cut in some cases), I'd recomment the `@FormParam`. Then the content is send via HTTP, not in the URL.

Comment: i meant to use xml/json in post data not as query param. I think OP doesn't know other ways to send a list, so i was just suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, you could serialize the List object and pass it as a string.